# Bash run multiple remote scripts in a shared session

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to build a `userdata` load sequence which is constructed of several external files:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/init.sh - | bash
$ echo "Some other custom commands"
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/more-stuff.sh - | bash
```

Now in `init.sh` there are some core functions that I need to use and they are not available in the other script sections since each one is a different bash session.

Is there are way to execute all these scripts and commands in one single bash session?

Answer (score 0):

you should download the scripts and then run with `source <filename>`. Then all defined variables and functions are available for the other scripts.

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/init.sh ~/s3_init.sh
$ chomd 750 ~/s3_init.sh
$ source ~/s3_init.sh
...
```

For cp-options in aws s3 see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: Yeah, I thought maybe theres a way to execute a remote file and make it create variables that will be accessible to the script who called this remote file